# is there possible to declare multiple url's in ajax post?

Tags: jquery

```
 Is there possible to add multiple url's in ajax post method?

 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: root + "projects/partners?json",
            data:{key:$(this).val()}
            success: refreshMyModel,
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

In above js file example i want to add muliple url's instead of one so is this possible  using ',' between multiple  url ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the multiple urls? If you want to load multiple jsons from multiple urls you should have multiple ajax calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible out of the box, you have to make multiple Ajax call, you can chain them together if it's important.